# click a button and make a div hide in a collapsable accordion

Tags: jquery, button

Collapse a repeated accordion in a website with the click of a repeated button

I have an accordion button,(using the 'panel-default' and 'panel-collapse' classes of bootstrap 3) that is repeated in the same page several times.
Beneath this accordion button there is another button, also repeated several times in the same page.
When I click on an specific button, I want it to collapse the specific accordion that it's above it, by the means of jquery.

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading accordion-toggle question-toggle " data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#faqAccordion" data-target="#infoAccordion" aria-expanded="false">
       <h4 class="panel-title">Edit Info</h4>
    </div>
    <div id="infoAccordion" class="panel-collapse collapse in" style="" aria-expanded="false">
         <div class="panel-body">
             some info
         </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-12  col-sm-12  col-xs-12 text-right pan">   
    <button class="nochg-btn">No Change</button>                
</div>
```

I've already tried:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".nochg-btn").click(function(){
          $(this).siblings(".panel-collapse").collapse("hide");

        });
    });
```

also:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".nochg-btn").click(function(){

          $(this).parent().siblings(".panel-default").addClass("collapsed");
          $(this).parent().children(".panel-collapse").removeClass("collapse");
          $(this).parent().children(".panel-collapse").removeClass("in");

        });
    });
```

and:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".nochg-btn").click(function(){
          $(event.target).closest('.panel-default').find('.panel-collapse').addClass("collapse");
          $(event.target).closest('.panel-default').find('.panel-collapse').addClass("in");
        });
    });
```

all to no avail. If anyone could help me detect what is wrong in the jQuery, I will very much appreciate it!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     <script>
          $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".nochg-btn").click(function(){
               $(this).parents('.root').find(".panel-collapse").collapse("hide");
            });
        });
        </script>
        <div class="root">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading accordion-toggle question-toggle " data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#faqAccordion" data-target="#infoAccordion" aria-expanded="false">
       <h4 class="panel-title">Edit Info</h4>
    </div>
    <div id="infoAccordion" class="panel-collapse collapse in" style="" aria-expanded="false">
         <div class="panel-body">
             some info
         </div>
    </div>
    </div>

<div class="col-md-12  col-sm-12  col-xs-12 text-right pan">   
    <button class="nochg-btn">No Change</button>                
</div>
</div>



<div class="root">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading accordion-toggle question-toggle " data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#faqAccordion" data-target="#infoAccordion" aria-expanded="false">
       <h4 class="panel-title">Edit Info</h4>
    </div>
    <div id="infoAccordion" class="panel-collapse collapse in" style="" aria-expanded="false">
         <div class="panel-body">
             some info
         </div>
    </div>
    </div>

<div class="col-md-12  col-sm-12  col-xs-12 text-right pan">   
    <button class="nochg-btn">No Change</button>                
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: it works!!! I tried to work it around without having to create yet an additional div with a class (in your case you use root) by coding it like:

   $(this).parents('.panel-default').find(".panel-collapse").collapse("hide");

But still didn't work and now I just don't understand why do I need an additional div to make the .parents work properly lol